# MDX works fine in MDX studio. Once i use it in SSRS i get the follwoing error "The query must have at least one axis. the first axis .."

Tags: reporting-services, mdx

When using *MDX studio* my code runs fine, once i use that same code in SSRS I get the error, "the query cannot be prepared: The query must have at least one axis

I have tried switching rows and columns and have seen similar problems but unable to replicate my desired output using those solutions

```
WITH 
    MEMBER [Version].[Version].[Product Long Desc] AS 
         iif([Product].[Product].CurrentMember.Level.Ordinal=1, "TOTAL",[Product].[Product].CurrentMember.Member_Caption) 
    MEMBER [Measures].[Trans] AS iif([Product].[Product].CurrentMember.Level.Ordinal=1,
         [Measures].[Customers],[Measures].[Transactions]) 
    MEMBER [Measures].[ACP] AS iif([Product].[Product].CurrentMember.Level.Ordinal=1,
         [Measures].[ACP Customers],[Measures].[ACP Transactions]) 
    MEMBER [Measures].[AIC] AS iif([Product].[Product].CurrentMember.Level.Ordinal=1,
         [Measures].[AIC Customers],[Measures].[AIC Transactions]) MEMBER [Version].[Version].[Measure Name] 
            AS CASE [Measures].CurrentMember.Member_Caption WHEN "Sales Units" 
            THEN "UNITS" WHEN "Customers" THEN "TRANS." WHEN "Transactions" THEN "TRANS." 
            WHEN "ACP Customers" THEN "ACP" WHEN "AIC Customers" THEN "AIC" WHEN "Reg Sales Avg Retail Selling Price" 
            THEN "AIP" ELSE [Measures].CurrentMember.Member_Caption END 
    MEMBER [Version].[Version].[Comparable LY Perc] AS 
        ([Version].[Version].[Version No].[ACT % ON LY],[Like for Like].[Like for Like].[Like for Like Adj Ind].&[1]) 
    MEMBER [Version].[Version].[Actual YTD] AS 
        ([Version].[Version].[Version No].&[1],[Accumulation].[Accumulation].[YTD]) 
    MEMBER [Version].[Version].[LY YTD] AS 
        ([Version].[Version].[Version No].&[5],[Accumulation].[Accumulation].[YTD]) 
    MEMBER [Version].[Version].[Comparable LY Perc YTD] AS 
        ([Version].[Version].[Version No].[ACT % ON LY],[Like for Like].[Like for Like].[Like for Like Adj Ind].&[1],[Accumulation].[Accumulation].[YTD]) 
      MEMBER [Version].[Version].[LY Perc YTD] AS 
        ([Version].[Version].[Version No].[ACT % ON LY],[Accumulation].[Accumulation].[YTD]) 
    MEMBER [Product].[Product].[TOTAL C&GM] AS 
        Aggregate({[Product].[Product].[Business Unit No].&[4],[Product].[Product].[Business Unit No].&[5],[Product].[Product].[Business Unit No].&[6],[Product].[Product].[Business Unit No].&[7]}) 
    MEMBER [Product].[Product].[TOTAL C&GM (Incl CRG)] AS 
        Aggregate({[Product].[Product].[Business Unit No].&[4],[Product].[Product].[Business Unit No].&[5],[Product].[Product].[Business Unit No].&[6],[Product].[Product].[Business Unit No].&[7],[Product].[Product].[Business Unit No].&[8]}) 
    SELECT {[Version].[Version].[Product Long Desc],[Version].[Version].[Measure Name],[Version].[Version].[Version No].&[1],[Version].[Version].[Version No].&[5],[Version].[Version].[Comparable LY Perc],[Version].[Version].[Version No].[ACT % ON LY],[Version].[Version].[Actual YTD],[Version].[Version].[LY YTD], 
 [Version].[Version].[Comparable LY Perc YTD],[Version].[Version].[LY Perc YTD]} ON COLUMNS,({[Product].[Product].[Company No].&[2],[Product].[Product].[Business Unit No].&[4],[Product].[Product].[Business Unit No].&[5],[Product].[Product].[Business Unit No].&[6],[Product].[Product].[Business Unit No].&[7],[Product].[Product].[TOTAL C&GM], 
 [Product].[Product].[Business Unit No].&[8],[Product].[Product].[TOTAL C&GM (Incl CRG)],[Product].[Product].[Business Unit No].&[3]},{[Measures].[Sales],[Measures].[Sales Units],[Measures].[Trans],[Measures].[ACP],[Measures].[AIC],[Measures].[Reg Sales Avg Retail Selling Price]}) 
ON ROWS FROM [WW Performance Business View]WHERE ([Location].[Location].[Chain No].&[243],tail(Filter([Time].[Time].[Fin Week],[Time].[Time].Properties( "Compl Wk Ind" )="1"),1).item(0))
```

to have the code run in visual studio the way it does in MDX studio if that is possible

Comment: Can you post output of query from MDX studio?

Answer (score 0):

Nice `MDX` !! Quite a big script.
I started to change the format a bit to see what is happening:

```
WITH 
    MEMBER [Version].[Version].[Product Long Desc] AS 
         iif(
              [Product].[Product].CurrentMember.Level.Ordinal=1, "TOTAL",[Product]. 
              [Product].CurrentMember.Member_Caption) 
    MEMBER [Measures].[Trans] AS iif([Product].[Product].CurrentMember.Level.Ordinal=1,
         [Measures].[Customers],[Measures].[Transactions]) 
    MEMBER [Measures].[ACP] AS iif([Product].[Product].CurrentMember.Level.Ordinal=1,
         [Measures].[ACP Customers],[Measures].[ACP Transactions]) 
    MEMBER [Measures].[AIC] AS iif([Product].[Product].CurrentMember.Level.Ordinal=1,
         [Measures].[AIC Customers],[Measures].[AIC Transactions]) MEMBER [Version].[Version].[Measure Name] 
            AS CASE [Measures].CurrentMember.Member_Caption WHEN "Sales Units" 
            THEN "UNITS" WHEN "Customers" THEN "TRANS." WHEN "Transactions" THEN "TRANS." 
            WHEN "ACP Customers" THEN "ACP" WHEN "AIC Customers" THEN "AIC" WHEN "Reg Sales Avg Retail Selling Price" 
            THEN "AIP" ELSE [Measures].CurrentMember.Member_Caption END 
    MEMBER [Version].[Version].[Comparable LY Perc] AS 
        ([Version].[Version].[Version No].[ACT % ON LY],[Like for Like].[Like for Like].[Like for Like Adj Ind].&[1]) 
    MEMBER [Version].[Version].[Actual YTD] AS 
        ([Version].[Version].[Version No].&[1],[Accumulation].[Accumulation].[YTD]) 
    MEMBER [Version].[Version].[LY YTD] AS 
        ([Version].[Version].[Version No].&[5],[Accumulation].[Accumulation].[YTD]) 
    MEMBER [Version].[Version].[Comparable LY Perc YTD] AS 
        ([Version].[Version].[Version No].[ACT % ON LY],[Like for Like].[Like for Like].[Like for Like Adj Ind].&[1],[Accumulation].[Accumulation].[YTD]) 
      MEMBER [Version].[Version].[LY Perc YTD] AS 
        ([Version].[Version].[Version No].[ACT % ON LY],[Accumulation].[Accumulation].[YTD]) 
    MEMBER [Product].[Product].[TOTAL C&GM] AS 
        Aggregate({[Product].[Product].[Business Unit No].&[4],[Product].[Product].[Business Unit No].&[5],[Product].[Product].[Business Unit No].&[6],[Product].[Product].[Business Unit No].&[7]}) 
    MEMBER [Product].[Product].[TOTAL C&GM (Incl CRG)] AS 
        Aggregate({[Product].[Product].[Business Unit No].&[4],[Product].[Product].[Business Unit No].&[5],[Product].[Product].[Business Unit No].&[6],[Product].[Product].[Business Unit No].&[7],[Product].[Product].[Business Unit No].&[8]}) 

SELECT 
{
[Version].[Version].[Product Long Desc]
,[Version].[Version].[Measure Name]
,[Version].[Version].[Version No].&[1]
,[Version].[Version].[Version No].&[5]
,[Version].[Version].[Comparable LY Perc]
,[Version].[Version].[Version No].[ACT % ON LY]
,[Version].[Version].[Actual YTD]
,[Version].[Version].[LY YTD]
,[Version].[Version].[Comparable LY Perc YTD],[Version].[Version].[LY Perc YTD]} 
ON COLUMNS

,({[Product].[Product].[Company No].&[2],[Product].[Product].[Business Unit No].&[4],[Product].[Product].[Business Unit No].&[5],[Product].[Product].[Business Unit No].&[6],[Product].[Product].[Business Unit No].&[7],[Product].[Product].[TOTAL C&GM], 
 [Product].[Product].[Business Unit No].&[8],[Product].[Product].[TOTAL C&GM (Incl CRG)],[Product].[Product].[Business Unit No].&[3]},{[Measures].[Sales],[Measures].[Sales Units],[Measures].[Trans],[Measures].[ACP],[Measures].[AIC],[Measures].[Reg Sales Avg Retail Selling Price]}) 
ON ROWS 
FROM [WW Performance Business View]
WHERE ([Location].[Location].[Chain No].&[243],tail(Filter([Time].[Time].[Fin Week],[Time].[Time].Properties( "Compl Wk Ind" )="1"),1).item(0));
```

....then I realised the problem: in `SSRS` you are only allowed to place `[measures]` on columns. It is a limitation of `SSRS` when using `MDX` so you will need to re-write the script ... sorry not a nice answer but just a limitation of the tool.

Here is a reference confirming some of the limitations: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/0d2b3e04-0fae-418b-a7ed-01c26147b839/mdx-works-fine-in-ssms-but-not-in-query-designer?forum=sqlreportingservices

p.s. `MDX Studio` rocks! I wish MS had adopted it and developed it further.

Comment: Thanks so much for the feedback. I have figured it out

Answer (score 0):

The reason i was struggling with this problem was because MDX studio does not allow one to create more than two axis and generates an error, while when i have two axis and it works in MDX studio, SSRS complains about measures on column so instead of re-writing my MDX i developed a 3rd axis in SSRS, used a matrix to unpivot my column that will get placed on rows. This is quick solid solution. However please note that by following this approach one would have to Dev in SSRS and not in MDX studio. Thanks for the assistance guys